# AJAX submit form, return success

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, addition

As the title suggests I'm using ajax to send form results to an external file.

The jQuery works perfectly (that is, the form appears when I click the relevant link) until I add the Ajax - then the whole thing breaks.

I've looked over it dozens of times and I really can't see what I'm doing wrong.

jQuery + ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change_shelves").click(function(){
        $("#add_to_shelf").fadeIn(function(){});

    });

    $("#add_to_shelf_submit_button").click(function(){
        var shelfID = $('#shelf').val();

        $.ajax({                        
            type: "post",
        url: "add_to_shelf.php",
        data: "shelfID=" + shelfID + "&bookID=" + <?php $_GET['id'] ?>,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#add_to_shelf").fadeOut(function(){});
                            $("#success").fadeIn(function(){});
                    }
    });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<p id="on_shelf">This book is on your <a href="want_to_read.php">want to read</a> shelf. <span id="change_shelves"><a href="#">Change shelves</a></span>.</p>

<form style="display: none;" id = "add_to_shelf" method="POST" action="add_to_shelf.php">
            <select name = "shelf">
                <option value = "1">Read</option>
                <option value = "2">Want to Read</option>
                <option value = "3">Reading</option>
            </select>
            <input type = "submit" id="add_to_shelf_submit_button" value = "submit" name = "Submit" />
        </form>
    <p style="display: none;" id="success">Shelf updated.</p>
```

The external file `add_to_shelf.php` is a non-issue - the data is successfully submitted when using jQuery only, so I know the file is correct.

Comment: Is that typo or an extra `});` in the line just before the last one?

Comment: What is the concrete problem, what does 'the whole thing breaks' mean?

Comment: Ok, it's working now. I needed to remove the action in the form to get the ajax to work.

Comment: Ok, scratch that. Now it works but the whole page refreshes meaning the shelfID never gets sent. Breaks means nothing happens - just a page refresh.

Comment: Look my answer, you have to prevent submitting.

Comment: Now nothing is added to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no element with an associated ID of `shelf`; this will fail:

```
var shelfID = $('#shelf').val();
```

Plus make sure you use `preventDefault()` inside any onClick event on input elements like:

```
$(...).onClick(function(e){(
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This prevents the form form being submitted like a typical non-AJAX one.

---

There also might be a problem in using `$('#shelf').val()` to get the selected option anyway. Try this instead:

```
$('#shelf option:selected').val();
```

---

To troubleshoot you could try use `.post()` instead of `.ajax()`. I've found this a lot handier.

```
$("#add_to_shelf_submit_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var shelfID = $('#shelf').val();
    alert('#add_to_shelf_submit_button clicked');
    $.post("add_to_shelf.php", {"shelfID": shelfID, "bookID" : <?php $_GET['id'] ?>}, function(data){
            alert(data);//response from add_to_shelf.php
    });
});
```

I'm assuming here that you know that `$_GET['id']` is the value taken from the current page send the POST request to the PHP and is gotten before any of the JS is even loaded.

Make sure you validate $_GET['id'] before using it. The way it is now, anyone could inject anything into your JS (at least).

Comment: I moved `e.preventDefault()` to after the variable declarations and it works! Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 4):

The select "shelf" does not have an ID attached.

```
var shelfID = $('#shelf').val();
```

would be undefined.  Add an ID to the select and it should work

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be recognising the ajax at all now. When I click 'submit' on the form it brings me to `add_to_shelf.php`. Why is it directing me away?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
success: function () { ...
```

by this

```
success: function (data) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#add_to_shelf_submit_button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
```

to avoid submitting.

Comment: Now nothing is added to the database.

Comment: Open the console and look if you're sending correct parameters and values to ajax.

Comment: Getting no errors in the console. Besides, I know it is working because it works fine when I remove the ajax.

Comment: So your ajax call is working, all the POST parameters are sending expected values and PHP is not outputting any error?